# Angular 6: Best way to handle user specific requirements

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an Angular app in which I have 10 different users/customers. Now each user wants different features and different text to be shown based on their requirements. Right now I am doing it using if else. Is there any better way to handle user specific requirements?

Comment: For me this is more like user preference/ personalization requirement. This can be best achieved by having user specific state in application database and  Angular application will use it after user login to display user specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be to,

- Have a generic component to display the features/text.
- Have a static template file or an interface that holds the constants with respect to each of the customers.
- Have input parameter to the generic component created in step 1 to identify the customers.
- Now based on the input retrieve the value from the static file/interface/template and feed the values to the html of the generic component.
- In feature, if there more customers it would require to add additional constant value in the static file/interface/template rather than changing/touching the component files.
- If you have database connected to your app, you can save the details in database instead of static files, and retrieve the same in the generic component based on the input to display the values with respect to each of the customers.

Answer (score 0):

> different features and different text to be shown based on their requirements

It is always recommended to involve `Server side handling` than the `client side` when we are dealing with different users.

Yes, we can handle this with client side but when App goes on it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your components with Generics, they wouldn't care about data model so different service might be able to use it.

As for customizing the view — Angular has interpolation (`{{variable}}`), templates (`*ngTemplateOutlet`) and dynamic components (`*ngComponentOutlet`). To be able to easily switch between all of those methods I created a tiny library that you can feed all those things and it would use the correct Angular method:

https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/ng-polymorpheus

I also wrote an article about customization and reusable components:

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/agnostic-components-in-angular-2427923b742d

Your question was pretty brief so this might not be what you are looking for, but this approach might help you create components that you could easily customize differently depending on your client needs.